# How to get history/logs of Wifi Hotspot names?

Tags: android, wifi, wifimanager, hotspot

I just want to get SSID of wifi hotspot. Below code snippet is enough to get current wifi hotspot name, but I want previous one.

```
try {
    WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    Method getWifiApConfigurationMethod = manager.getClass().getMethod("getWifiApConfiguration");
    WifiConfiguration  config = (WifiConfiguration) getWifiApConfigurationMethod.invoke(manager);
    Log.e("CLIENT", "SSID:" + config.SSID);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please help...

Comment: I don't think there is way to find out this, I could not find any method for this

Comment: But Android maintains a log file for configuration details. Can we read that file?

Comment: can you share log file path where it stores ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get previously associated wifi networks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255539/how-to-get-previously-associated-wifi-networks)

Comment: @TGMCians That's the thing i dont know!

Comment: @yong.k This is about personal wifi hotspot

Comment: The WiFi network created by the hotspot is still a WiFi network, thus the duplicate target still matches